# Desktop microphone causes subwoofer to vibrate

Tags: desktop, microphone

I have a cheap desktop microphone and some Klipsch Promedia speakers.
The microphone used to work with these speakers, but now when the microphone is on, it causes the subwoofer to vibrate, increasing as the volume is increased.
There also is a static pop whenever I turn the microphone on or off.

Why does this happen, and are there any solutions short of wearing headphones?

Comment: Add a subsonic filter to the mic input?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities... feedback or grounding issue.

The vibration could be acoustic feedback - well-known to any audio engineer. Sound from the sub is travelling through the floor, desk etc directly to the mic, which is then sending that sound straight back to the speakers... & round we go.

The only solution is turn it down, or physically isolate one from the other. Put the sub somewhere else; isolate it from the floor or desk on speaker spikes or neoprene feet. Put the mic on a stand or soft surface.... or wear headphones.

If it's not feedback, then the alternative is it could be an un-grounded connection & the vibration is 50 or 60Hz generated by the mains voltages nearby. Fix would be check the circuit is clean & undamaged. This vibration would increase directly in a linear fashion with the speaker volume. Feedback would suddenly get louder & louder as you turn up the volume, yet disappear completely at low volumes; grounding hum would only totally disappear at no volume.

The pop is probably that the mic input gain is relatively low compared to the audio path's output gain; therefore the switching is relatively loud compared to the signal it's getting from your voice.
Solution would be to investigate whether you have sufficient input gain & see if increasing it [within reason] would help. Skype has a visual indicator of input gain. Switch off auto-gain & see if that helps too.

Alternatively, the mic switching pop is a direct result of the above-mentioned grounding issue.